# Back shared element transition between activities

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I use native Android Transition API to animate transition between activities. Here's the source I use to launch activity:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, imageView, imageView.getTransitionName()).toBundle();

        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

When I tap on hardware back button it returns to previous activity with expected reversed transition animation, but when I tap on "Up" button in Toolbar it returns to previous activity with default animation:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following code to the activity, that is being finished:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            supportFinishAfterTransition();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

<sup>[Source](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition)</sup>